# How can I limit user operations per minute in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this web application using **NodeJS (Express)** and **MongoDB**. I made a little bot that makes 1000 HTTP requests which read and write in my MongoDB database.

Imagine a hacker makes the same bot and has the correct credentials, he will clearly be able to spend all my monthly connections/operations I have with MongoDB.

Is there a way to set a maximum value for operations per minute per user in MongoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the npm package **express-rate-limit** :

```
const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit')

const apiLimiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 28800000, //8 hours
  max: 250,
  message: 'You have exceeded the 250 requests in 8 hours limit!', 
  headers: true,
});
```

You can set this in each route:

```
app.use(apiLimiter);
```

Or in a specific `/api` route:

```
app.use("/api/", apiLimiter);
```